# sed command correct usage in bash

Tags: bash, sed

I have writetn the followig commands :

```
F_NAME = IMAGE.ZIP
F_DATE="$(date +'%d_%m_%Y')"

NAME=`echo $F_NAME | sed 's/.zip/$F_DATE/'`
```

This is giving an output :

```
 IMAGE$F_date
```

the output should have been `IMAGE02_12_2016`

What is wrong in my NAM command ?

How do i print the systimestamp with "IMAGE" 
like IMAGE01_12_2016_11_22_11

Comment: Use double quotes.

Comment: and for timestamp ?

Comment: use `%H_%M_%S`.